# Dynamic Sender profile is Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email

I know it's a popular issue and I have referred to existing discussions, but nothing helped :(

I am trying to create a dynamic sender profile to send emails from different from names based on language

I have created a content block with the AmpScript below

```
 %%[
var @fromName, @locale 
Set @locale = [Locale]

if @locale == 'es' then
set @fromName = 'Test A'

elseif @locale == 'fr' then
set @fromName = 'Test B'

elseif @locale == 'de' then
set @fromName = 'Test C'

elseif @locale == 'it' then
set @fromName = 'Test D'

elseif @locale == 'pt-BR' then
set @fromName = 'Test E'

else /* fallback if neither evaluates to true */

set @fromName = 'Test A'
endif
]%%

%%=v(@fromName)=%%
```

And I have this value provided in the sender profile which I have created,

> %%=ContentBlockbyID("78992")=%%

But when I try to send a test send or to send a live launch to a test data extension, the email itself is not been sent :(

It would be of great help if you can help me fix this issue?

Thanks & regards,

Siva

Comment: Did you enable the functionality through support? In most accounts this is not enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

Siva,

Make sure your MC account is enabled with "Enhanced sender profile" Functionality, If not please raise a support ticket and involve your account executive to enable the functionality